# Problems looping through objects

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have objects that are created from a HTML table, each object is a row in said table. They look like this:

```
function rowObj(aName,suctionTemp,liquidTemp,outsideTemp,boxTemp,foodTemp1,foodTemp2,foodTemp3,foodTemp4,suctionPsi,liquidPsi,
            compressorAmps,condensorFan,evaporatorFan,mainPower,doorSwitch,input2,input3,input4,hour,minute,amPm){
this.aName=aName,
    this.suctionTemp=suctionTemp,
    this.liquidTemp=liquidTemp,
    this.outsideTemp=outsideTemp,
    this.boxTemp=boxTemp,
    this.foodTemp1=foodTemp1,
    this.foodTemp2=foodTemp2,
    this.foodTemp3=foodTemp3,
    this.foodTemp4=foodTemp4,
    this.suctionPsi=suctionPsi,
    this.liquidPsi=liquidPsi,
    this.compressorAmps=compressorAmps,
    this.condensorFan=condensorFan,
    this.evaporatorFan=evaporatorFan,
    this.mainPower=mainPower,
    this.doorSwitch=doorSwitch,
    this.input2=input2,
    this.input3=input3,
    this.input4=input4,
    this.hour=hour,
    this.minute=minute,
    this.amPm=amPm;

};
```

What I am trying to do is loop through these objects and get the time where the unit is on.  I can do this by:

```
var minuteArray=[];
for ( var key in objects){
    if (objects[key].compressorAmps > 0 && objects[key].condensorFan > 0){
        minuteArray.push(objects[key].minute);
    }else{
        key++;
        break;
    }
}
var firstMinute= minuteArray.shift();
var lastMinute=minuteArray.pop();

var hourArray=[];
for ( var key in objects){
    if (objects[key].compressorAmps > 0 && objects[key].condensorFan > 0){
        hourArray.push(objects[key].hour);
    }else{
        key++;
        break;
    }
}
var firstHour= hourArray.shift();
var lastHour=hourArray.pop();
```

Here, I am pushing all the values into an array and then taking the first and last element and getting the hour and minute from these.  This allows me calculate how long it has been running.  This is also only giving me the current run time. Ultimately I want to: 
1. Store each set of running values in an array
2. Then the values when it equals 0 in an array
3. Then keep going and store the next set, where it is > 0, in a different array

```
    for ( key in objects){
    if ( objects[key].compressorAmps > 0 && objects[key].condensorFan > 0){
        //store values in an array until compressorAmps === 0, skip those
        //then store the next set, where compressorAmps >0 in a different array
    }else if (objects[key].compressorAmps === 0 && objects[key].condensorFan === 0){

    }
}
```

I did not know if this was possible, and if it is, I am having a very hard time figuring it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: So the objects created by `rowObj` are stored where? In an array? And are they stored in time order?

Comment: No, in the variable objects.  Looks like this:

Comment: To break down your question further, you want to, basically, store *runs* of values where `compressorAmps == 0` or `compressAmps > 0` into a set of array?

Comment: objects
{0: rowObj, 1: rowObj, 2: rowObj, 3: rowObj, 4: rowObj, 5: rowObj, 6: rowObj, 7: rowObj, 8: rowObj, 9: rowObj, 10: rowObj, 11: rowObj, 12: rowObj, 13: rowObj, 14: rowObj, 15: rowObj, 16: rowObj, 17: rowObj, 18: rowObj, 19: rowObj}

Comment: Why would you do that? Use an array. That's what arrays are for. Then you can use a simple `for` loop. `for...in` doesn't guarantee the order that the keys will be iterated.

Comment: Yes essentially.  I will have, lets say 4 rows where amps >0, then 3 rows where amps ==0, then 3 rows where amps >0.  I want to store the first 4 rows and get the time difference between them.  Skip the 3 rows, then store the next 3 rows in a different variable.

Comment: Yes I know, this is part of a larger project.  That's why I have put the values that I get into an array.  I can easily get it to store all the values that don't ===0 into one array, but that isn't what I want.  I like the use of objects here for other parts of the project.

Comment: Once i have them in an array, i have no way of checking the value of the compressorAmps(I don't think).  I am checking the compressorAmps, then storing the timestamp from it.

Comment: You can store objects in arrays. Arrays are actually objects too. But with some specific properties and syntax for handling them.

Comment: And as a general comment, when you have a function taking that many parameters, you should probably think about refactoring it. Some where you are, presumably, selecting a row from the table. Probably that function should create the object there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put you values in an array sorted by time (I assume that's what you want). Then all you need to do is iterate through your array, testing each value and looking for the edge condition. So something like:

```
var result = [];    // this will be a 2D array with your results
var curr = null;    // this is the current run
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
     if (data[i].compressorAmps > 0) {   // test condition, change as needed
         if (!curr) {                    // if we don't have a run, start one
             curr = [];
         }
         curr.push(data[i]);             // store the current value
     } else {
        if (curr) {                      // if this is the end of a run
            result.push(curr);           // save the run
            curr = null;
        }
     }
}
```

Now you can iterate through `result` and take the first and last of each run to calculate the time:

```
for (var i=0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var start = result[i][0];
    var end = result[i][result[i].length - 1];
    console.log("Run started at: " + start.hour + ":" start.minute);
    console.log("Run ended at: " + end.hour + ":" end.minute);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! That seemed to do pretty much what I wanted.  I had to tweak it a little, but it got me on the right path.  I think I can get to where I am going with this now. Thank you so much.